# How might a video website be blocking direct access to the flv/mp4 files?

Tags: vlc-media-player, lua

I've been trying to tinker with making VLC support video websites that aren't included in the default distribution. When I view the source of the video webpage, I am able to extract something that looks like a http url to the video files (in several different formats, even). But if this is pasted into a browser tab, I get a big nasty *Forbidden 403* error.

Obviously this is to deter people snarfing videos directly. But does anyone have any insight as to how they might be accomplishing it? I don't think it's cookie-based, else it would likely work in the same browser that I opened the video webpage in. Does the Flash player send a different http header than my browser, something like that?

I don't need a perfect solution, just someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try grabbing the video with an established video ripper like keepvid and then look at the URL it uses.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, hot-linking is tracked by the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) (sic) field. This tells the webserver what URL sent you to the current request. If it's empty, or not from a valid website, then you're hotlinking! It's fairly easy to spoof, though.

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to spoof it from lua. Coming up with the correct url for the referrer will be easy, but I don't know if VLC's lua lets you manipulate that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I installed the Spoofy extension, and I figured out how to get curl to  do that as well. Both got 403s. I'm looking at the view-source of the video's webpage, and I don't see any obvious javascript trickery.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it seems that the URLs to the videos were designed to be temporary, with some Apache mod checking that a hashed timestamp was recent enough. I had left the "view source" tab open for several hours.

I've managed to get my lua script working, and can now watch the videos directly in VLC. If anyone has any requests, I could probably whip something up for you.

Comment: This doesn't even really seem to answer your original question.  This answer needs a great deal of work.

Comment: @Ramhound It could probably be expanded on slightly, but it does answer his question. How does a site block direct access? -> By using temporary URLs and expiring them after a time. While not the only method, it's one of many.